# r readline() function is repeating the prompt over and over again even before waiting for an input

Tags: r, while-loop, readline

I have a readline function inside while loop that gives me options of choosing the code block. While loop continues on until condition changes. (e.g. TRUE to FALSE) Strange thing is that following code below will iterate for about 20 times until it asks me for an input.

```
option <- readline(prompt=paste("Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options:
                                      1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.","There is exact inning to fill the inning: ",torf,sep=""))
```

It makes my console ugly by repeating following:

```
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      inning <- ((sample_home$IP[i] %/% 1 + (((sample_home$IP[i] %% 1) * (10/3)))) / 9)
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      ER <- ifelse((blank_home$LW[2] * inning) - (blank_home$LW[3] * inning) - (sample_home$LW[i]) + (4.25 * inning) < 0, 0, ER <- round((blank_home$LW[2] * inning) - (blank_home$LW[3] * inning) - (sample_home$LW[i]) + (4.25 * inning),digits=0))
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      if(ER < 0)
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      {
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE        sample_home$ER[i] <- 0
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE        
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      }
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      if(ER >= 0)
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      {
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE        sample_home$ER[i] <- ER
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE        
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      }
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE      
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE    }
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE    
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE    name <- as.character(sample_home$PlayerName)
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE    
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th. No crossover. Choose three options: 1) MLE from 25-man. 2) Call up someone from outside 25-man.There is exact inning to fill the inning: TRUE    for(i in 1:length(name))
Home team. Needing MLe for 8th...
```

It appears like it took in the line of codes after the readline functions as an input. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. The line works fine for me, given that `torf = TRUE`. Do you run it with `source("script.r")` or copy/paste with the rest of the code? Try the `source` function.

Comment: Can you post more parts of your code? Or is this single line already your reproducible example?

Comment: got it nya. That was exactly the problem. Thank you!